# В функции std::stod используется запятая

Tags: c++

Почему `std::stod` требует указания запятой для дроби, а не точки?

```
std::cout << "\n1=" << std::stod("0.5" ); // вывод 0
std::cout << "\n2=" << std::stod("0,5" ); // вывод 0.5
```

- Это берется из языковых настроек системы?
- Можно ли исправить это программно?

Comment: Недавно был такой вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/211103/c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А если вот так:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_us");
```

З.Ы. обратно так:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
```

Подробнее [здесь](http://cppstudio.com/spravochnik/standartnye-zagolovochnye-fajly-iz-si-v-s/zagolovochnyj-fajl-clocale-locale-h/funkciya-setlocale/)

Comment: Вот так работает: 

setlocale(LC_ALL,"English");

И так setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

Хотя я ожидал увидеть какие нибудь интересные махинации с самим std::